# page url {$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}

Tags: php, smarty

i order current page using this code {$smarty.server.PHP_SELF} but page come with .php i want it to come with .html is there a way to do it using php or any way?

other thing that i want is to redirect any user use .php to .html on same page?

Comment: iam tring to make my site friendly url using .htaccess

RewriteRule ^ar/(.*)\.html$ /$1.php?language=arabic [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$  $1.php?language=english [NC,L]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `htaccess` for that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```